# Open popup when someone clicks on an image/button

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup

Basically, I want to create a popup (that collects emails) that appears when someone clicks on an image that acts like a button.

I've placed the following in footer.php (I've replaced my uuid and lid with "xxxx" for privacy considerations:

```
<script>
function showMailingPopUp() {
    require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us11.list-manage.com","uuid":"xxxx","lid":"xxxx"}) })
    document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
};

document.getElementById("open-popup").onclick = function() {showMailingPopUp()};
</script>
```

Next, I tried to make an image of a download button act as a button that, when clicked, opens the popup. I hoped to do that by adding id="open-popup" (again replaced link with "xxxx"):

```
<img id="open-popup" class="aligncenter" style="cursor: pointer;" src="xxxx" alt="" />
```

But it only opens the popup the first time I load the page and click on the image. When I close the popup and click on the image again the popup isn't loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is because require.js doesn't want to load `Loader` one more time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `document.getElementById`

Try writing your `img` tag using `onClick` to call the function

`<img class="aligncenter" style="cursor: pointer;" src="xxxx" onClick="showMailingPopUp()" alt="" />`